# Simplest method to create an OpenFileDialog and return the pathname to edittext box using MFC applications

Tags: c++, mfc

How to create a MFC application in which I want to implement an OpenFileDialog box and the resultant path name to be displayed on the edittext box.

Comment: Have you read about CFileDialog?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk77e5e7.aspx

Comment: Your title doesn't match the question. To create an MFC app you should use Visual Studio's Wizard (File->New->Project->Visual C++->MFC, and select MFC Application).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example that will help you get started:

```
const TCHAR szFilter[] = _T("CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv|All Files (*.*)|*.*||");
CFileDialog dlg(FALSE, _T("csv"), NULL, OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT, szFilter, this);    
if(dlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
{
    CString sFilePath = dlg.GetPathName();
    m_FilePathEditBox.SetWindowText(sFilePath);
}
```